# How to make a working Submit button on HTML?

Tags: php, html, css

The question is how do i make the submit button work so if they press submit, the ff will be send to my email (ex: example@gmail.com).'
If PHP is needed please post the code so i just gonna paste it on my code :D ty

```
<div id="forms">
<form class="form">
<p class="name">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
</p>
<p class="email">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" />
</p>
<p class="text">
<textarea name="text" placeholder="Describe your logo" /></textarea>
</p>
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
```

I cannot find the answer in the existing question of this, So i decided to make another one... the existing is like 2 years ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to put a mailto `action` on the `<form>` tag, i.e.:

```
<form class="form" action="mailto:someone@example.com">
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change your form tag to look like this:

```
<form action="mailto:address@example.com">
```

This will send unformatted data to your email address without needing PHP. If you would rather format it in a specific way, then you can use the [PHP mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

I also removed `class="form"`. Typically this is not needed, but it depends on your reason. If you are using class for CSS you can just reference the element `form` rather than the class name `.form`.